# is there Best tutorials for WinRT developement?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I am already familiar with the WPF, Silverlight and Windows phone platforms....

Is there very good tutorials over the internet to learn the WinRT Metro style applications ?

Comment: Subjective and argumentative question that will likely be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check next resources:

- App overview - [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- UI guideline - [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx)
- Samples - [there](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/)
- Performance tips - [there](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/performance-win8-metro-xaml)
- Localization - [there](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/04/26/localize-windows-8-application.aspx)

Comment: One of the best tutorials for Windows 8 development: http://www.win8tutorial.net

Comment: @ChristianMoser not sure